# How to get Android APK install link in email using Circle Ci

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I was using Buddybuild CI/CD for my project. As buddybuild will not support Android from 1st march, we are switching our project to Circle Ci. In Circle Ci, we have to create YML file and push the code. It will trigger the APK. That APK is stored in the Circle Ci dashboard only. From there, We can download and send it to mail. I want continuous deployment in my mail like Buddybuild, rather than I manually mail it to everyone.

Once again, I need an Install build of different flavours in my Email, rather than I manually send it to everyone from Circle Ci dashboard. I am not receiving an install link as we get used to get in buddybuild as below:

[image]

The YML file that I used is as follows:

```
    version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/code
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-26-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx4608m
    branches:
          only:
            - master
            - staging
            - develop
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_test_results:
                path: app/build/test-results
                destination: test-results/
      - run:
          name: Initial build
          command: ./gradlew clean assembleRelease --no-daemon --stacktrace
      - store_artifacts:
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/
          destination: apks/
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a command in the CircleCI config to send the .APKs via email. Either using `sendmail` (least reliability in terms in delivery due to SPAM protections), G Suite (if you have it), or a SaaS service like SparkPost.

Respectfully,

Ricardo N Feliciano
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: Hi Feliciano, I am not getting how we can use sendmail. Can you please send some sample code to get clear idea of it?

Comment: This can provide you more information on how to use sendmail: https://clients.javapipe.com/knowledgebase/132/How-to-Test-Sendmail-From-Command-Line-on-Linux.html

Comment: @FelicianoTech Can you provide sample code or article to configure with G Suite ?

Comment: You can follow this guide for setting up sendmail with Gmail, which is what G Suite uses for email: https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay